# Does Alan Moore hate Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, comics, league-of-extraordinary-gentlemen, alan-moore

I finally got around to reading *The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen: Century 2009* and I still puzzling over some of it.
**Warning! Major Spoilers ahead!**

> The Anti Christ seems to be a parody of Harry Potter

And in one scene:

> The Anti Christ kills a character by firing a gigantic lightning bolt out of his penis. (Of course, he does.)

I can't make up my mind: is this parody, hatred, satire? All? Neither?

Has Alan Moore made any statements explaining a relation between the comic and the Harry Potter franchise?

Comment: Does Alan Moore hate Harry Potter? Surely a better question would be "Is there anything that Alan Moore *doesn't* hate?"

Comment: How is "firing a gigantic lightning bolt out of his penis" hate statement?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Judging from the plot description on the [LXG wiki](http://lxg.wikia.com/wiki/Antichrist), it sounds more like a [postmodernist deconstruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmodernism#Deconstruction), something that Moore is well known for (*Watchmen* did it for the entire genre of Superhero comics and is credited for almost single-handedly bringing about [the Dark Age of Comic Books](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheDarkAgeOfComicBooks)).

The basic premise of Harry Potter is pure escapist juvenile wish fulfillment - "Hey, you're not just an orphan who gets bullied, you're a wizard! And not just any wizard, you're destined to save the world!!!". Of course, it goes beyond that and becomes considerably [darker and edgier](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DarkerAndEdgier), but the basic premise practically screams for deconstruction.

So that's what Moore does:
the kid's adventures turn out to be entirely staged, designed to prepare him for being the Antichrist. And I doubt it was the result of any particular dislike of Harry Potter - perhaps it was simply born out of the sudden inspiration "hey, what if Harry's scar was actually the Mark of the Beast?"

Comment: +1 to you sir! Mr Moore maintains that LoEG is satire, however, he does mention cultural decline as well regarding Harry Potter; http://www.guardian.co.uk/books/2012/jun/18/alan-moore-extraordinary-antichrist-harry-potter

Comment: -1 for unannounced TVTropes link ambush :)

Comment: Alan Moore is himself a practicing wizard/magician. Worships a Roman snake-god and everything. I'm sure I've seen some disparaging remarks about Harry Potter somewhere in something he's written... maybe the Fossil Angels essay... hate is probably too strong a word, but I think he does have a negative opinion of harry potter -- or its version of magic, at least.

Comment: Based on some interviews, Moore genuinely does seem to dislike the Potter books.  I'm not a fan of them, but it seems so arbitrary to me.  There's so much more loathsome stuff out there ...